# C#: String inside Last brackets() of a string

Tags: c#, regex, string, indexof, brackets

In one of my tasks, I have to find the ID of bugs inside last set of brackets in the Bug status. I have listed some sample bug status.

Bug Status (String) looks like,

```
Case 1: Bug A is resolved (XID: X015)
Case 2: Bug B is resolved (ZID: X016)
Case 3: Bug C is resolved (Data issue) (SID: X017)
```

For case #1 and #2 , i coded like, finding the first occurrence of ( and ), and calculated the value inside the brackets.

```
var start = value.IndexOf("(", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1;
var end = value.IndexOf(")", start, StringComparison.Ordinal);
var BugID = value.Substring(start, end - start);
```

But in Case #3, there are two sets of bracket , first one contains the summary about bug, next one is the actual bug ID and I need to extract bug ID.
I have to code something like this,

```
var start = value.IndexOf(last "(");    //index of last (
var end = value.IndexOf(last ")");  //index of last )
var BugID = value.Substring(start, end - start);
```

Any suggestion would be helpful!

Comment: What about `IndexOf(last, "(ID:")`?

Comment: That vary accordingly. :( . Bracket only constant. I have edited the samples accordingly. @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: what about `value.LastIndexOf("(")`

Comment: There is also such things as regular expressions... Might help in this case.

Comment: I believe if you did `.Split(':')` on the string, then your ID should be inside the return `string[]` object as `splitString[1]`. There may however be a trailing space which can be removed easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
  String source = "Some (123) test (valid value) with ugly -> ( <- tricks";
  String result = null; // what if source doesn´t have brackets?

  int pClose = source.LastIndexOf(')');

  if (pClose >= 0) {
    int pOpen = source.LastIndexOf('(', pClose);

    if (pOpen >= 0)
      result = source.Substring(pOpen + 1, pClose - pOpen - 1);
  }

  ...
  // "valid value"
  Console.Write(result);
```

Comment: Don't know why everyone is so obsessed with regex when a simple `LastIndexOf` does the trick. +1 to you Sir.

Answer (score 2):

Try the LastIndexOf(...) string method.

```
var start = value.LastIndexOf(" (") + 1;
```

Comment: There's an *ugly test* which will be failed: `"(wrong) then (right value) then trick ("`, please notice the last dangling `"("`

Answer (score 2):

```
var strings = new List<string>
{
    "Case 1: Bug A is resolved (XID: X015)",
    "Case 2: Bug B is resolved (ZID: X016)",
    "Case 3: Bug C is resolved (Data issue) (SID: X017)"
};

foreach (var s in strings)
{
    var result = s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf('('));

    System.Console.WriteLine(result.Trim('(', ')'));
}
```

returns:

XID: X015

ZID: X016

SID: X017

EDIT: Use Trim() to get rid of the brackets!

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are your friend. [`Regexp.Matches()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/h9ee7wwd(v=vs.110).aspx) method will find all occurances of given pattern:

```
var text = @"Case 1: Bug A is resolved (XID: X015)
Case 2: Bug B is resolved (ZID: X016)
Case 3: Bug C is resolved (Data issue) (SID: X017)";

// Instantiate the regular expression object.
Regex r = new Regex(@"\([^)]*\)", RegexOptions.Multiline);

// Match the regular expression pattern against a text string.
var matches = r.Matches(text);
if(matches.Count > 0)
{
     var last_match = matches[matches.Count - 1];
     Console.WriteLine(last_match.Groups[0].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some working code that will pull the ID numbers out. It includes the X, assuming you want that.

```
var lines = new[]
{
    @"Case 1: Bug A is resolved (ID: X015)",
    "Case 2: Bug B is resolved (ID: X016)",
    "Case 3: Bug C is resolved (Data issue) (ID: X017)"
};

foreach(var line in lines)
{

    Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=[(]ID:\s)X\d*(?=[)])");

    Match match = regex.Match(line);

    if(match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

And if you ever want to play around with Regex, here's a nice tool to do so with:

https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

With Regexp, you can write it like this (tested with LINQPad):

```
void Main()
{
    string a = "Bug A is resolved (XID: X015)";
    string b = "Bug B is resolved (ZID: X016)";
    string c = "Bug C is resolved (Data issue) (SID: X017)";

    var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(\([^(]*\))$");

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("a: {0}", regex.IsMatch(a) ? "YES" : "NO"));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("b: {0}", regex.IsMatch(b) ? "YES" : "NO"));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("c: {0}", regex.IsMatch(c) ? "YES" : "NO"));

    var aMatches = regex.Matches(a);
    var bMatches = regex.Matches(b);
    var cMatches = regex.Matches(c);

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("a: {0}", aMatches[aMatches.Count - 1]));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("b: {0}", bMatches[bMatches.Count - 1]));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("c: {0}", cMatches[cMatches.Count - 1]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var str = "Bug C is resolved (Data issue) (SID: X017)";
        var index = str.IndexOf("ID: ");
        Console.WriteLine(index);
        // + 4 is the length of the string "ID: "
        // so again we are subtracting it back along with -1 to remove the last paranthesis
        str = str.Substring(index + 4, str.Length - index - 4 - 1);
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```